# How can I get ember-cli to pickup my .jshintignore?

Tags: ember-cli

ember-cli is giving me hinting errors about a test file like `mirage/config.js:` and I want to disable the ember-cli hints.

I've tried creating a **.jshintignore** file with:

```
mirage/*
app/mirage/*
```

In both **/** and **/app** and I've created **app/mirage/.jshintignore** with:

```
*
```

Nothing is letting me ignore whole folders. Do I have any options besides placing a jshint directive in each file?

Comment: Maybe thats why: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/4586

Comment: @victorleungtw The person submitting that issue looks eerily familiar.